# How to solve import error after npm start

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just started using react and i am following a tutorial. I have the same code as him but i am getting the following error.

#### ./src/index.js

Attempted import error: './components/App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App')###

Here are my index and component file.

my index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import  App from './components/App';


ReactDOM.render(

  <App/ >,document.getElementById('root')

)
```

my App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>Ageteller Component</div> 
    )
  }   
}
```

Comment: how are you exporting from App?

Comment: You didn't export the class: export default class App extends Component { ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export your App component.

Under the component put `export default App`

It should look like:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>Ageteller Component</div> 
    )
  }   
}

export default App
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The guy didnt import and his code ran, i have no idea how lol

Answer (score 0):

export the App Component
Try following

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'; 
    export default class App extends Component {
      render(){
        return(
          <div>Ageteller Component</div> 
        )
      }   
    }
```